# Как провалидировать несколько полей одновременно в yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, валидация

Здравствуйте. Делаю сайтик для записи к врачу
Есть форма:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-add-record']); ?>
        <?= $form->field($record, 'doctor_fio')->dropDownList($arr, ['prompt' => 'выберите ФИО врача']) ?>
        <?= $form->field($record, 'date')->input('date') ?>
        <?= $form->field($record, 'time')->input('time', ['step' => 600]) ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Записаться', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'add-record-button']) ?>
        </div>
        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

К ней экшн:

```
public function actionRecord()
{
    $record = new Record();
    $arr = Record::generateDocArr();
    $record->user_fio = Yii::$app->user->identity->fio;
    if($record->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if($record->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Вы успешно записались');
            return $this->refresh();
        } else Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Ошибка');
    }
    return $this->render('record', ['record' => $record, 'arr' => $arr]);
}
```

Нужно сделать функцию для валидации сразу всех полей, чтобы нельзя было записаться к тому же врачу, в тот же день в то же время. Сомневаюсь, что это вообще можно назвать валидацией, но хотелось бы знать, как организовать это?
По сути, нужно сделать проверку на то, есть ли в таблице уже такие значения полей time, data и doctor_fio, и если есть, то выдать ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, создать свою функцию валидацию и привязать ее к определенному полю.

Например:

```
class Record extends ActiveRecord
{
    // you code

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // you code
            [['time', 'data', 'doctor_fio'], 'required'],
            ['doctor_fio', 'validateRecord'],
        ];
    }

    public function validateRecord($attribute)
    {
        // Условие в выражение where установите то, которое вам нужно. 
        // Ниже приведен как пример.
        $exist = self::find()
            ->where([
                'time' => $this->time,
                'date' => $this->date,
                'doctor_fio' => $this->doctor_fio,
            ])->exists();
        if ($exist) {
            $this->addError($attribute, "Запись на это время не возможна");
        }
    }

    // you code
}
```

Весь остальной код у вас останется без изменения.

Дока http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

Это все еще можно назвать валидацией. Кроме своей функции, вы также можете использовать встроенный \yii\validators\UniqueValidator, и свойство targetAttribute,
с помощью которого можно указать комбинацию полей, по которым будет проверяться уникальность, а также атрибуты, к котором применится ошибка

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#unique

```
[
    ['time'], 
    'unique', 
    'targetAttribute' => ['time', 'data', 'doctor_fio'],
    'message' => 'На это время уже есть запись к этому врачу, выберите другую дату'
],
```